# OpenGL + gtkglextmm + glade

Tags: opengl, glade, gtkmm

when I am programming with "gtkmm", there is a widget **"Gtk::DrawingArea"**.
I can program that widget *"by hand"* (so write the code) or more elegant way is to use "glade" user interface designer, where I can do the same *"graphically"*.

Now I am trying to connect OpenGL with gtkmm through "gtkglextmm" library. In that library, there is a widget **"Gtk::GL::DrawingArea"** - but this widget **"IS NOT"** available in glade.

So is there any way to program with "OpenGL + gtkglextmm" using "glade" (for the "graphical user interface" part)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all libglade is an old library. If you are writing new project start with [gtk builder](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Builder.html).

As you can see [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-builder-using-derived-widgets.html.en) gtkmm provide easy way to create your own widgets and see them (almost) in glade tool. You simply insert plain DrawinArea widget to window and then tell gtk-builder to put in this place yours derived class.

Here is all together:

Setting up gtk-builder:

```
refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file(ui_file);

GlDrawingArea*glArea = NULL;
refBuilder->get_widget_derived("drawing_gl",glArea);
```

Opengl DrawingArea class:

```
 class GlDrawingArea : public Gtk::DrawingArea ,
                       public Gtk::GL::Widget<GlDrawingArea>
 {                   
 public:             
         GlDrawingArea(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& builder);
         virtual ~GlDrawingArea();
 protected:          
         void on_realize();
         bool on_expose_event(GdkEventExpose* event);
         bool on_configure_event(GdkEventConfigure* event);          
 private:
         Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder;
 };
```

Constructing opengl drawingarea:

```
// GlDrawingArea:
GlDrawingArea::GlDrawingArea(BaseObjectType*cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& builder)
        : Gtk::DrawingArea(cobject),
          refBuilder(builder),
          screen_tex(0)
{                                                                                               
        //
        // Configure OpenGL-capable visual.
        //
        Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::GL::Config> glconfig;

        // Try double-buffered visual
        glconfig = Gdk::GL::Config::create(Gdk::GL::MODE_RGB    |
                                           Gdk::GL::MODE_DEPTH  |
                                           Gdk::GL::MODE_DOUBLE);
        if (!glconfig) {
                std::cerr << "*** Cannot find the double-buffered visual.\n"
                          << "*** Trying single-buffered visual.\n";

                // Try single-buffered visual
                glconfig = Gdk::GL::Config::create(Gdk::GL::MODE_RGB |Gdk::GL::MODE_DEPTH);
                if (!glconfig) {
                        std::cerr << "*** Cannot find any OpenGL-capable visual.\n";
                        std::exit(1);
                }
        }

        // print frame buffer attributes.
        GLConfigUtil::examine_gl_attrib(glconfig);

        //
        // Set OpenGL-capability to the widget.
        //
        set_gl_capability(glconfig);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much "qba".
So the key was in using "derived" widgets.